# XCode 6 Framework issue: Module [framework] has no member named [class]

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift, xcode6

I have built a custom framework that I have pulled into a workspace containing an application I am writing using Xcode 6.  I am getting an error when I try to instantiate a class belonging to the framework reading Module 'Framework' has no member named 'Unit':
[image: I am getting an error when I try to instantiate a class belonging to the framework reading Module 'Framework' has no member named 'Unit]

I have made sure to link the application target to the library created by the framework:
[image: I have made sure to link the application target to the library created by the framework]

Here is a screenshot of the Unit class:
[image: Here is a screenshot of the Unit class]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  I don't see anyone else that has experienced this issue.  I would be forever indebted to anyone that could help me troubleshoot this issue.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I feel very dumb right now.  I thought that the default access level was public for everything defined in my Framework.  I was able to fix this issue by making the class and the initializer public.

Comment: I can tell about your feeling...