# Module 'Fabric' has no member named 'with'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, twitter-fabric

I installed Fabric framework via cocoapods. My project can detect Fabric header and import statement doesn't give any error. But calling

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

gives error

> Module 'Fabric' has no member named 'with'

I checked similar problems in [with custom framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829207) and in [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/200), but those didn't help.

**Update:** 
I tried running in dummy application and using the pod in it and it worked fine. Seems only to happen in current project, but can't find a reason for it.

Comment: Try reinstalling and file a bug with Fabric. PS, I've had unimaginable issues with Fabric, Twitter, etc cocoa pods. What I did was delete derived data, clean the project, quit Xcode, and then do it again. Sometimes I had to do that 5x and it works.. @Sahilkapoor

Comment: Tried all that. No help.

Comment: What's your deployment target? Try changing it to a lower one (or higher).

Comment: Deployment target is 8.0. Tried 7.0 and 9.0. Same error.
It was working fine till morning since 3 months. But suddenly this error started coming.

Comment: Did you try re-installing Fabric through the Fabric OS X  app? I'm trying to give you different things that I've done/attempted when having similar issues. Hope one helps. I don't have a clear solution, but rather many attempts and options that I've worked (and most have worked) as mentioned above. Either way, definitely file a bug.

Comment: Yeah, tried that too thrice. Filing a bug. Will update if I get a response or solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Try creating a dummy application and using the pod in it. May be its your app specific ??

Comment: Yeah it is indeed app specific. Not happening elsewhere. What could be the the problem in that case?

Comment: Did you `import Fabric` and `import Crashlytics`?

Comment: Yes. And they were working fine few hours ago.

Comment: Fabric.xcodeproj -> Build Phases -> Complie Sources. If it is empty, then add Fabric.

If it is not empty, clean and build. Tell me if it works.

Comment: There's no Fabric.xcodeproj file. I am usinig cocoapods.

Comment: Oops sorry. Verify if Fabric is there in your project's Compile Sources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96880/discussion-between-sahil-kapoor-and-harikrishnan-t).

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it.

Apparently, another pod 'AWSS3' inserted Fabric.h in their own framework in their latest release. Had to downgrade their pod to previous version to make it run.

Reported [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/286). I will update if I get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Add import Firebase to the same file where you use Fabric.